# Unable to Reverse the text using 'for' Loop Function

Tags: python-3.x, reverse

I want to reverse the string using the Loop & Function. But when I use the following code, it is output the exact same string again. But it suppose to reverse the string. I can't figure out why.

```
def reversed_word(word):
    x=''
    for i in range(len(word)):
        x+=word[i-len(word)]
        print(i-len(word))
    return x


a=reversed_word('APPLE')
print(a)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the output of your debug statement (the `print` in the function), you'll see you're using the indexes `-5` through `-1`.

Since negative indexes specify the distance from the *end* of the string, `-5` is the `A`, -4 is the first `P`, and so on. And, since you're appending these in turn to an originally empty string, you're just adding the letters in the same order they appear in the original.

To add them in the other order, you can simply use `len(word) - i - 1` as the index, giving the sequence `(len-1) .. 0` (rather than `-len .. -1`, which equates to `0 .. (len-1)`):

```
def reversed_word(word):
    result = ""
    for i in range(len(word)):
        result += word[len(word) - i - 1]
    return result
```

---

Another alternative is to realise you don't need to use an index at all since iterating over a string gives it to you one character at a time. However, since it gives you those characters in order, you need to adjust how you build the reversed string, by *prefixing* each character rather than appending:

```
def reverse_string(word):
    result = ""
    for char in word:
        result = char + result
    return result
```

This builds up the reversed string (from `APPLE`) as `A`, `PA`, `PPA`, `LPPA` and `ELPPA`.

---

Of course, you could also go *fully* Pythonic:

```
def reverse_string(word):
    return "".join([word[i] for i in range(len(word), -1, -1)])
```

This uses list comprehension to create a list of characters in the original string (in reverse order) then just joins that list into a single string (with an empty separator).

Probably not something I'd hand in for classwork (unless I wanted to annoy the marker) but you should be aware that that's how professional Pythonistas usually tackle the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your word is `python`.

You loop will then iterate over the values `0` through `5`, since `len(word) == 6`.

When `i` is `0`, `i-len(word)` is `-6` (note carefully that this value is *negative*). You'll note that `word[-6]` is the character six places to the left from the end of the string, which is `p`.

Similarly, when `i` is `1`, `i-len(word)` is `-5`, and `word[i-len(word)]` is `y`.

This pattern continues for each iteration of your loop.

It looks like you intend to use positive indices to step backward through the string with each iteration. To obtain this behavior, try using the expression `len(word)-i-1` to index your string.

Comment: Brian, `len(word) - i` will you you an index error on the first iteration. I suspect you meant to say `len(word) - i - 1`, yes?

Answer (score 0):

```
def reversed_word(word):
    reversed = ''
    for i in range(len(word)-1, -1, -1):
        reversed += word[i]
    return reversed

print(reversed_word("apple"))
```